# Manipulate string inside {} in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new on Angularjs. I making some test and I couldn't find out if is there way to do something like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="article in articles" class="thumbnail">
    <img  ng-src="{{encodeURI(article.image)}}"></a>
</li>
```

The idea is to manipulate the string with a native JS function.

Comment: looks like a good candidate for a filter as @ganaraj suggested: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.templates.filters.creating_filters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You dont have to use the interpolate directive in these scenario's. You can use something that is much more understandable , like a function.

```
<li ng-repeat="article in articles" class="thumbnail">
<img ng-src="encode(article.image)">
</ii>
```

Now encode should be a function in either the scope that contains the articles or in the inner scope (Note : ng-repeat creates a new scope for each item it creates. So in this example for each article there will be a new scope ).

Lets say your controller is called ArticleCtrl ( I am going to assume )

```
function ArticlesCtrl($scope){
    $scope.articles = [];
    $scope.encode = function(url){
        return encodeURI(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, is a good solution. I have created a custom filter to resolve it, so now I do something like this:
`<img ng-src="{{article.img | encodeURI}}">`
What do you think is the best approach?

Comment: To me it looks like the filter is a better approach. Mostly because that is write one fire many times approach and I am assuming you would have to encode uri in more than 1 controller. If you do my approach you would have to write this in all the controllers which need that functionality. A filter seems appropriate unless someone else has an opinion as to why that wont fit in this case or something.